# how to convert bytes to binary using python

Tags: python, binary, byte

so i want convert bytes to binary in python, but when i run it, there's none in the result and i got error:

> 'NoneType' object is not iterable

here's the code i tried

```
 //func biner
    def biner(password):
        print(password)
        password[0]
        for my_byte in password:
            print(f'{my_byte:0>8b}', end=' ')
    
    //func to use the result from func biner
    def skalar(key, biner):
        if len(key) <= key_bytes:
            for x in range(len(key),key_bytes):
                key = key + "0"
    
        jumbin2 = len(key)
        print(jumbin2)
    
        jumbin = biner
        print(biner)
    
        hasilenkrip = ''
        for a in jumbin:
            hasilenkrip += a * jumbin2
    
        print(hasilenkrip)
    
    //how i called the func
    enc = b'l\x87\x87\xe6'
    ky = maru
    tes = biner(enc)
    tes1 = skalar(ky, tes)
    print(tes1)
```

Comment: Your function currently returns `None` because there's no `return` statement. Perhaps instead of using `print`, you should modify your functions to return an array of outputs

Comment: how to change print(f'{my_byte:0>8b}', end=' ') to use return? @BenGrossmann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function currently returns `None` because there's no `return` statement. Perhaps instead of using `print`, you should modify your functions to return an array of outputs.

I suspect what you have in mind is something like this.

```
#  //func biner
def biner(password):
    print(password)
    password[0]
    return ' '.join(f'{my_byte:0>8b}' for my_byte in password)

#     //func to use the result from func biner
def skalar(key, biner):
    if len(key) <= key_bytes:
        for x in range(len(key),key_bytes):
            key = key + "0"

    jumbin2 = len(key)
    print(jumbin2)

    jumbin = biner
    print(biner)

    hasilenkrip = ''
    for a in jumbin:
        hasilenkrip += a * jumbin2
    return hasilenkrip
    
#     print(hasilenkrip)

#     //how i called the func
enc = b'l\x87\x87\xe6'
ky = maru
tes = biner(enc)
tes1 = skalar(ky, tes)
print(tes1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
some_bytes = int(input('Enter bytes: '))

print(f'{some_bytes>>4:04b}{some_bytes&0xf:04b} ({some_bytes})')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).